# jqgrid no pager for local data

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid, which expects data from four different sources, what I have done is, I make four different ajax calls, and then add the returned rows to the grid in a loop.

The problem is, the pager does not work any more, instead it displays a scroll bar.

I read that after version 3.7 jqgrid does support paging for local data, I am using 4.1.2, but it does not work.

I believe there must be a parameter that needs to be set, I just cant seem to find it.

Thanks,
Ali

Comment: The problem should be *how* you fill the local data. Could you post your code?

Comment: $.each(Response, function(i, item){
 jquery("#grid").jqgrid("addRowData",i+1,item)
}

Answer (score 0):

the usage of `addRowData` is the wrong way. It is not only slow, but it don't support paging and sorting. You will have to reload the grid once to see the data correct.

Much more effective way is to fill all data in an array of items. Every item should has an additional `id` property. Then you should *create* the grid with additional parameter `data: items` and use `gridview: true` additionally to have better performance.